# PyInstaller --noconsole still shows the console after running the app

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, console

I've built an app to download and play sound everytime someone inserts or removes USB drive from PC.
Code:

```py
from playsound import playsound
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
from time import sleep
from typing import Callable
import threading
import os
import youtube_dl
import win32file


def play_audio():
    try:
        path = os.getcwd() + "\\audio.mp3"
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
            'outtmpl': path
        }

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0HTwQjMr9k'])

        playsound(path)
    except Exception as e:
        toast = ToastNotifier()
        toast.show_toast("RIP prank failed byq", "no ogolnie prank failed rip co jest?", duration=20)


def get_drives():
    drive_list = []
    drivebits = win32file.GetLogicalDrives()
    for d in range(1, 26):
        mask = 1 << d
        if drivebits & mask:
            drname = '%c:\\' % chr(ord('A') + d)
            t = win32file.GetDriveType(drname)
            if t == win32file.DRIVE_REMOVABLE:
                drive_list.append(drname)
    return drive_list


def watch_drives(on_change: Callable[[dict], None] = print, poll_interval: int = 1):
    def _watcher():
        global prev
        while True:
            drives = get_drives()
            if prev != drives:
                on_change(drives)
                play_audio()
                prev = drives
            sleep(poll_interval)

    t = threading.Thread(target=_watcher)
    t.start()
    t.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    prev = get_drives()
    watch_drives(on_change=print)
```

I don't understand it but everytime the download starts and FFmpeg starts debugging everything (using youtube-dl) a couple of console windows appear for a fraction of a second and they immediately disappear. How can I TOTALLY disable the console so that even FFmpeg can't open it?

**EDIT:** Yes, I've already tried using `--windowed` and `-w` parameters in PyInstaller

Comment: It sounds like PyInstaller's `--noconsole` option prevents the standard console window from being displayed; however if your code or the libraries you're using are calling external programs that themselves have console windows, there's no way you could just automatically prevent all that via PyInstaller, since those are completely separate applications. Does that make sense?

Comment: try to add `'quiet':True` in `ydl_opts`

Comment: @buran it didn't work...